# Evaluating the residue of $(1 - e^{-z})^n$ at $z = 0$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus

For $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, I want to find a way to determine the residue of the function $f(z) := (1 - e^{-z})^n$ at $z = 0$.

I must admit that I haven't come too far yet. In case that $n ≥ 0$, $f$ wouldn't have any isolated singularities, so does that mean that the residue would simply be $0$? So the more interesting point would be how the residue looks in case that $n < 0$, where we indeed have a singularity at $z = 0$. One way to determine the residue would certainly be to determine the Laurent expansion, but I don't really know how one could do that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Another way that came to my mind would be Cauchy's integral formula, where we would need to integrate over a circle around $z = 0$, parameterized by e.g. $\gamma: t \mapsto e^{it}$. So if we set

$$Res(f; 0) = \frac{1}{2πi} \int_\gamma (1-e^{-z})^n dz$$

that would look like a more useful/easy approach to me. But I don't really know how to evaluate this integral. Maybe we could use Cauchy's integral theorem to shift the integration to something easier? It would for example be nice if we could substitute something like $t = 1 - e^{-z}$, but I don't know if we could actually do that. I'm not really all that certain.

Comment: Try expanding $e^{-z}$: $$ \frac{1}{1-e^{-z}} = \frac{1}{1-(1-z+z^2/2!-z^3/3!+\cdots)} = \frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-z/2!+z^2/3!-z^3/4!+\cdots}. $$ Remember that the residue is the coefficient of the $1/z$ term in the Laurent expansion.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach. Does that mean though that I can get the residue by simply setting $z=0$ in the term $\frac{1}{1 - z/2! + z^2/3! ...}$ (and get $\frac{1}{z} \cdot 1$ and therefore the residue $1$)? Or isn't it that easy? I'm not really sure how to continue from there on.

Comment: It's not _quite_ setting $z=0$. You're actually looking at $\lim_{z\to0}zf(z)$ (which equals 1: this is a bit like saying "$f(z)$ approaches $1/z$ for small $z$").

Comment: @amcerbu Ok, that makes sense, thanks. Is there a way to carry over this solution to the other $n < 0$? Because If we expand $e^{-z}$ in the formula $\frac{1}{(1-e^{-1})^n}, n ≥ 2$, we would actually pull out $\frac{1}{z^n}$ if we were to use the same strategy, and therefore don't get the coefficient for the $\frac{1}{z}$ coefficient, would we? (And if we only pull out one $\frac{1}{z}$, then the $\frac{1}{(1-e^{-1})^{n-1}}$ would make the limit go against $\infty$ and we therefore wouldn't get the residue either.)