# Residue of $(1-e^{-z})^{-n}$ at 0

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Similar to [Evaluating the residue of $(1 - e^{-z})^n$ at $z = 0$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603025/evaluating-the-residue-of-1-e-zn-at-z-0-with-n-in-mathbbz), but this question is unanswered.

What is the residue at $0$ of $(1-e^{-z})^{-n}$?

For $n=1$, we can just differentiate $1-e^{-z}$ and so $\text{res}_0f=1/1=1$, but for $n>1$ I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3):

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\frac{1}{(1-e^{-z})^n}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{dz}{(1-e^{-z})^n}\stackrel{z\mapsto \log(1+t)}{=}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{dt}{(1+t)\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\right)^n} $$
equals
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{(1+t)^{n-1}}{t^n}\,dt = \color{red}{1}$$
for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$. We have just exploited the binomial theorem and the fact that $\log(1+t)$ is a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of the origin such that $g(0)=0$. In particular it maps any simple closed contour around the origin in the region $|t|<1$ in a simple closed contour around the origin. This is the main idea of the Lagrange inversion theorem, see [this brief outline](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2741758/44121).

$\hspace{1cm}$[image]

This is how the contours $|z|=\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5}$ are transformed via $z\mapsto \log(z+1)$.